# GCC compiles with warning: unknown escape sequence: '\040'

Tags: c++, c, gcc

I am new to c programming. Here is my code:

```
int main() {
    char *loc = " E:\ ";
    return 0;
}
```

The program compiles successfully with a warning.

```
<source>: In function 'int main()':
<source>:4:17: warning: unknown escape sequence: '\040'
     char *loc = " E:\ ";
```

The output of the program is "E:", but it should be "E:\". Why I am missing the '\' in the output. Whats wrong in my code??

Comment: Use \\ to get a single \ in the string

Comment: You need to escape backslashes: `char *loc = " E:\\ ";`

Comment: why the c++11-tag? That doesn't even compile and is *not* the way how to use C++ properly.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I have tried "E:\\". But the output is now "E:\".

Comment: @Dr.pK Isn't that exactly the output you asked for??

Comment: And you should use `const char *` or use an array (`char loc[]`).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I am asking why my output miss '\' ??

Comment: @Dr.pK Because `'\'` is a special character (the escape character). To evaluate a single `'\'` it needs to be _escaped_ itself. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to write `E:\\` instead of `E:\`. This is because the `\` character marks the beginning of a [escape sequence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequence). Writing a `\\` is itself an escape sequence that just evaluates a `\`.

Comment: So, to print "E:\\\" , i have to assign char *loc = " E:\\\\\\ "....Right??

Comment: @Dr.pK You need to write "E:\\\\\\\\\" to print "E:\\\"

Comment: @Dr.pK Yes, for every "\" you want in the output you have to put "\\" in your string. In C++ exists bunch of characters that cannot be used in string literal directly. When you want to put such character in your string, you need to prepend it with "\" charaster. E.g. when you want ` " ` double quote, you write ` \" ` See [complete list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/escape) of these special characters.